# How to deal with an empty catch {} block with Webpack/Babel?

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, babeljs

I'm dealing with an issue I'm having when trying to run my local dev environment. I'm using Webpack 2 and Babel 6.

I can't seem to figure out how to get a package that contains empty catches to parse.

Is there a plugin for Babel to do so? Do I need to do something else?

```
[0] Module parse failed: C:\Users\PROJECT\node_modules\ssh2\lib\server.js Unexpected token (490:16)
[0] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
[0] |         try {
[0] |           socket.end();
[0] |         } catch {} << it's complaining about this section.
[0] |       },
```

.babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["add-module-exports"],
  "env": {
    "production": {
        "presets": ["react-optimize"],
        "plugins": [
          "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console",
          "babel-plugin-transform-remove-debugger",
          "babel-plugin-dev-expression",
          "add-module-exports"
        ]
    },
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-exponentiation-operator"]
    },
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        [
          "webpack-loaders",
          {
            "config": "webpack.config.node.js",
            "verbose": false
          }
        ],
        [
          "babel-plugin-module-alias",
          {
            "src": "test/electron/mockElectron",
            "expose": "electron"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Webpack dev config:

```
/* eslint max-len: 0 */
import webpack from 'webpack';
import baseConfig from './webpack.config.base';

const config = {
  ...baseConfig,

  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://localhost:3000/__webpack_hmr',
    '@babel/polyfill',
    './app/index'
  ],

  output: {
    ...baseConfig.output,
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/dist/'
  },

  module: {
    ...baseConfig.module,
    loaders: [
      ...baseConfig.module.loaders,

      {
        test: /\.global\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?sourceMap'
        ]
      },

      {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?modules&sourceMap&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    ...baseConfig.plugins,
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    })
  ],

  target: 'electron-renderer'
};

export default config;
```

Webpack base config:

```
import path from 'path';
import WebpackNotifierPlugin  from 'webpack-notifier';

export default {
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json-loader'
    }, {
        test: /\.cjs?$/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.cjs'],
    mainFields: ['webpack', 'browser', 'web', 'browserify', ['jam', 'main'], 'main']
  },
  plugins: [
    new WebpackNotifierPlugin({excludeWarnings: true})
  ],
  externals: [
  ]
};
```

Relevant packages:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator": "7.18.6",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding": "^7.18.6",
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
"@babel/preset-stage-0": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
"@babel/parser": "^7.19.0",
"@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.9",
"@babel/eslint-plugin": "7.18.10",
"babel-loader": "8.0.0",
"babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "1.0.4",
"babel-plugin-dev-expression": "0.2.1",
"babel-plugin-module-alias": "1.6.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "7.0.0-beta.3",
"babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
"babel-plugin-transform-remove-debugger": "^6.9.4",
"babel-plugin-webpack-loaders": "0.9.0",
"babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
"babel-preset-react-optimize": "1.0.*",
"babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
"babel-eslint": "~10.1.0",
"webpack": "2.7.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "2.0.6",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.25.2"
```

The package that causes the issue is ssh2 post 0.8.9. Any version from 1.0.0 onwards. From 1.0.0 the files seem to have a number of catch {} occurrences.

Comment: Please give a [mre] of your current config.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've added some more information for you. Hopefully this will be useful to you. BTW I'm aware that I've old babel packages in my package.json I'm just upgrading to webpack 2 so these will be removed soon. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding` in your babel configuration, please make sure you have it in the `plugins` options

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding"]
}
```

Reference docs: https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding